# Electric field of an infinite sheet of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration

I am trying to derive the formula for **E** due to an infinite sheet of charge with a charge density of $ \rho C/m^2$. I assumed the sheet is on $yz$-plane. I used Coulomb's law to get an equation and integrated the expression that over $yz$-plane. But, I have not succeeded in deriving the correct expression. The answer I am getting is $0$.

Below is the picture of my work. Kindly, have a look and let me know where did I make mistakes. 
In actual, **E** due to a charge sheet is constant and the **correct** expression is

**E** $=\rho/2\epsilon$<sub>0</sub> **a<sub>N</sub>** , where **a<sub>N</sub>** is unit vector normal to the sheet.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the electric field of an infinite flat 2D sheet of charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167753/)

Comment: Related : [Proving electric field constant between two charged infinite parallel plates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422818/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 (Gauss’ law):

Just simply use Gauss’ law:

$$\int_{\partial V}  \vec{E} \cdot \vec{da} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}.$$

A pillbox using Griffiths’ language is useful to calculate $\vec{E}$. The pillbox has some area $A$. And due to symmetry we expect the electric field to be perpendicular to the infinite sheet. Imagine putting a test charge above it, in which way does it move? Right, perpendicular to the sheet. Using $Q=\rho A$ for the charge enclosed in the pillbox we get:

$$ \rho A = \epsilon_0 \int_{\partial V} |\vec{E}| |\vec{da}| = \epsilon_0 \int_{\partial V} E da = \epsilon_0 E \int_{\partial V} da = \epsilon_0 (2AE), $$

since we expect $E$ to be constant for fixed distance for the infinite sheet. Note that the sides of the pillbox do not contribute to the integral since $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{da} = 0$ in that case.

All together we find that $E=\frac{\rho}{2 \epsilon_0}$ and the direction we thought already of is some unit vector $\hat{n}$ orthogonal to the infinite sheet:

$$ \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{2 \epsilon_0} \hat{n} .$$

Method 2: (Coulomb/direct calculation)
Another method goes as follows:

$$E=E_x= k \int \frac{x}{(r^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} r dr d\theta = 2\pi k \int \frac{xr}{(r^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} dr = 2\pi kx [ (r^2 + x^2)^{-1/2}]^0_{\infty} = 2\pi k x \frac{1}{x}=  2\pi k.$$ Let us see, I called $$k= \frac{\rho}{4 \epsilon_0 \pi}$$ we get indeed that $E=\frac{\rho}{2 \epsilon_0}$.

Errors in your calculation: 
- the $y$ in the nominator should be a $x$.
- missing term in the denominator, namely $z^2$ because now you consider an infinite line and integrate over a surface.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that it could solved using Gauss' law. I wanted to derive this using Coulomb's law. Even for that, I have a text book at my hand in which the expression is derived using Coulomb's law. But the strategy in the book is somewhat different. I wanted to derive it with the approach I have shown above and the thing I want to know is what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: Uhm okay that is a tough one...

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more easy using polar coordinates such that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and $y=r sin(\theta)$ ?

Comment: I don't see why I should use polar coordinates, it is a planer sheet. Anyway, I tried that too but didn't work out.

Comment: It evaluates to zero even if I use polar coordinates. Well, I guess that the problem is with formulation

Comment: Your integral does not hold. You are missing a $z^2$ term in the square root at the beginning. I mean $x^2+y^2$ should be $x^2 + y^2 +z^2$ in $(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}$ also.Then use $z^2 + y^2 =r^2$ to solve the integral. Then use $dA=dydz=rdrd\theta$ and integrate over these two variables. The $x$ should drop out at the end.

Comment: I added the solution!

Comment: Your welcome. I also had to dig in my previous classical electrodynamics courses , although I am at the moment studying much more complicated stuff like tensor algebra and representation theory of groups xD.

Comment: That's why I thanked you, you seemed to put considerable effort in answering the question. Seem like pretty advanced stuff that you mentioned. I hope to learn it in future. As for now, I am an engineering undergrad, very much interested in learning Physics.

Comment: @Mathphysmeister  I have solved this tons of times but suddenly I thought why is the total charge not 2$\rpho$A since there are two sides of the surface and the charge would on both the sides. Could you help if you wish

Comment: Because the charge in an area $A$ is simply given by $Q = \rho A$ since $\rho$ is a surface charge density, i.e. charge per unit area. The area is not $2A$. That is why your reasoning is not right.

Comment: @Mathphysmeister  if the charge is on both sides of the sheet and the charge density is rpho then then total charge on the sheet ( both sides combined since charge is both sides of the sheet and the charge density is constant) hence total charge is rpho*A + rpho*A.... I didn't get what you are trying to imply.. If the charge is on both sides you got to multiply by 2A

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do the integrations by hand? Because

$r = x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z}$

$r^\prime = y^\prime \hat{y} + z^\prime \hat{z}$

Should yield the correct answer, but the integrations are messy, unless you go to cylindrical coordinates

Comment: That is such a tedious and long method of dealing with this problem. See my added solution (method 2) how quick and easy it can be :)

Comment: You beat me to it. And not if you use mathematica :)

Comment: Actually, the integration for the y- and z-direction does take a few minutes. All that for a simple $0$.

Answer (score -2):

Use cylindrical coordinates. The field (on axis) of a ring of charge (radius $R$, charge density $\lambda$) goes like:

$$ E(z) = \frac{1}{2\epsilon_0}\frac{ R z}{(z^2 + R^2)^{\frac 3 2}} $$

then integrate over $R$, using:

$$ \int{\frac{ R z}{(z^2 + R^2)^{\frac 3 2}dR}}=-\frac z {\sqrt{z^2+R^2}}\rightarrow 1$$

Comment: That is what I did in my answer... does not matter but it does not contribute something new

Comment: if that's what you did in your answer, why is your answer wrong? It's hard to read, but it looks like you're using cartesian coordinates. Cyclindrical coordinates does produce $0$.

Comment: does _not_ produce $0$.