# Why is the electric field in a homogenic electric field always the same?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

When there is a charge between two parallel  plates why is the sum of both forces always equal where ever it stands between those two plates? When I say both forces I mean the negative side interacting with the charge and the positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now assuming that you have faith in the infinite plate assumption.
Assume a test charge $Q$.
Now keep it at a point between the plates. It would experience a force.
Now take that charge to another point between the plates.

So you can see the difference as you have named the points but the charge cannot as he will
still find the plates to be infinite.

For example take a sheet of paper keep it near your eyes(very near so that you don't see any ends).
now move it a little bit so that you cannot again see the ends

Will you find any difference?

ANSWER IS NO

now this was a bit intuitive
For formulae approach the electric field by a infinite sheet is independant of the distance.
$$\overrightarrow E=\sigma /2\epsilon_{o}$$
where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density.

Here is the link for the derivation of [expression for electric field for infinite](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/422965/277960) sheet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to two infinite parallel plates, then the electric field, E, between them is constant i.e. not dependent on location. Therefore, the force on a small test charge q between the plates, qE, is the same everywhere between the plates.

Comment: Yes, but why? Can you prove it to me mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

For the infinite parallel plate capacitor with separation $d$ along the $z$-direction, the most general field looks like:

$$ \vec E(x, y, z) = E_x(x, y, z)\hat x + E_y(x, y, z)\hat y + E_(x, y, z)\hat z  $$

Since the system is invariant under translations in $x$ and $y$, it cannot depend on $x$ or $y$:

$$ \vec E(z) = E_x(z)\hat x + E_y(z)\hat y + E_z(z)\hat z $$

It's also isotopic w.r.t to rotations about the $z$-axis, so there can be no horizontal components:

$$ \vec E(z) = E_z(z)\hat z $$

At this point, we can apply Maxwell's equation:

$$ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$

in the gap where $\rho=0$:

$$ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{dE_z}{dz} = 0 $$

which integrates to:

$$ E_z(z) = c $$

for some constant $c$.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.